# What is the difference between console.log("render") and React.useEffect(()=>console.log("render")) in functional component

Tags: reactjs

if I have a functional component like:

```
const Example = ({props})=> {
    console.log("render outside effect");
    React.useEffect(()=>console.log("render inside effect"))
}
```

What is the difference of both calls?

It would be equal with my understanding of functional react components. The function will be executed on each rerender, so all expressions and functions outside from useEffect will be executed?! The useEffect without Brackets would be also executed each rerender?

Is this a missunderstanding?

Thanks in advance

Tristan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useEffect` within a functional component is called once the render cycle is component

Both the console logs in your component will definitely be invoked on each re-render. However useEffect console.log will be re-rendered after react has finished the painting of the DOM however the `console.log()` directly inside the functional component will be executed before the DOM rendering is done

`useEffects` in react are used to run `subscriptions` or `sideEffects` based on `state or props` just like lifecycle methods in `React class components`

You can control when a `useEffect` will be executed using the `dependency` argument.